# Movimento de bola em jogo de volleyball está rápido demais

Tags: java, jogos, lógica

Há algum tempo estou desenvolvendo um jogo de *volleyball* em Java com a Slick2D, mas estou tendo um problema bem chato com o movimento da bola: não consigo fazer a bola realizar um movimento de parábola (personagem saca, a bola sobe, desce no outro personagem) decente e manter a velocidade legal para jogar.

update da classe `ball`

```
    float originalSpeed = (velocidade * InGameState.GetDeltaTime());
    // Movimentação no eixo X

        float speed;        
        if (distanceX < originalSpeed) {
            speed = distanceX;
        } else {
            if (distanceX > originalSpeed) {
                speed = originalSpeed;
            } else {
                speed = 0;
            }
        }

        if (this.x < this.targetPositionX) {            
            this.speedX = speed;
        } else {
            if (this.x >= this.targetPositionX) {
                this.speedX = -speed;
            }
        }

        // Movimentação no eixo Y                
        if (distanceY < originalSpeed) {
            speed = distanceY;
        } else {
            if (distanceY > originalSpeed) {
                speed = originalSpeed;
            } else {
                speed = 0;
            }
        }
        if (this.y < this.targetPositionY) {
            this.speedY = speed;
        } else {
            if (this.y >= this.targetPositionY) {
                this.speedY = -speed;
            }
        }


        float percentX;
        float percentY;      

        if (distanceX > distanceY) {
            if (Math.abs(distanceY) < 1) {
                percentX = 0;
            } else {
                percentX = (distanceX/distanceY);
            }
            percentY = 1;
        } else {
            if (distanceY > distanceX) {
                percentX = 1;
                if (Math.abs(distanceX) < 1) {
                    percentY = 0;
                } else {
                    percentY = (distanceY/distanceX);
                }
                percentX = 1;
            } else {
                percentX = 1;
                percentY = 1;
            }
        }

        // Aplicação da "velocidade"                    
        setX(this.x + (this.speedX * percentX));
        setY(this.y + (this.speedY * percentY));

    }
```

Da forma que está o código acima, às vezes a bola fica extremamente rápida (desconfio que seja quando o `percentY` ou o `percentX` ficam muito altos) e assim não dá para prever o movimento da bola. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, existem alguns problemas de conceito no método.

Se você quer realizar um movimento de parábola, tem que pensar em termos de uma [função quadrática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_quadr%C3%A1tica) do tipo `y = ax² + bx + c`.

O fato do seu código não ter nenhuma chamada a métodos que calculam raiz quadrado ou o quadrado mostra que não tem como o movimento parecer real. Além disso, comparar variáveis de distância com variáveis de velocidade não faz muito sentido, sendo que no mínimo torna o código confuso.

Além disso, é bom lembrar que na vida real o movimento de uma bola não é uma parábola perfeita, já que além da gravidade detalhes como a rotação da bola, vento e a resistência do ar influenciam no movimento.

Entretanto, ignorando os detalhes, o movimento da bola pode ser calculado em duas fases, considerando dois vetores de velocidade horizontal (`X`) e vertical (`Y`).

Primeiro, o movimento horizontal, no eixo `X`, pode ser constante pois não sofre interferência do vetor de força da gravidade. Opcionalmente você poderia acrescentar um pequeno fator de desaceleração devido à resistência do ar.

Segundo, o movimento vertical no eixo `Y`, poderia ser descrito por uma parábola baseada numa função quadrática, como descrita acima. Você precisa determinar os valores adequados de `a`, `b` e `c`. Isso pode ser feito estudando os [efeitos de cada fator na equação](http://www.marcelorenato.com.br/teoria/teoria_ensino_medio/welcome/ALTERADOS/funcao_2gr.htm). Com a equação determinada, basta substituir `x` em cada diferente posição e você obtém o valor aproximado de `y`.